# EJB taking long time to return data to Backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, glassfish-4

I have project which JSF 2 and Primefaces 5.2 in frontend. EJB3 and JPA with eclipselink for backend processing deployed on Glassfish 4 server.

Issue: For opening page I am fetching data using postconstruct method in backing bean which inturn calls EJB to get the data from DB.

Data fetches correctly but returning result from EJB to backing bean taking too long time.

Could you please help me on this issue.

Comment: To the backing bean or to the page on the client? Suggestion: use a profiler

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to give advices with so little informations. Anyway these are my suggestions:

1. Launch your database monitoring tool and see if the problem is at database level or in the business layer.
2. Tune your database or the query if necessary, consider using a native query as last option
3. If you have a large rowset returned, think about pagination, most modern JSF frameworks have components with built in functionalities.
4. Try to build queries that return just the data you need, es. pk, name, description... etc instead of the whole entity.